# Why is are there still folder permissions after replacing them by an icalcs command?

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I use the windows commandline tool icalcs to set access permissions to a folder. (The goal is to create a folder within c:/Programmfiles that can only be accessed by the local system account)
Admins should get full permissions, all others none.
After setting the permission, there are additional unexpected permissions:

```
S-1-15-2-1/ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:READ_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/READ_ACL:FILE_INHERIT/DIRECTORY_INHERIT:ALLOW
S-1-15-2-1/ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:DIRECTORY_INHERIT/INHERIT_ONLY:ALLOW
```

I cannot delete these permissions, and I wonder how to get rid of this.

I tried to remove the unwanted entries via the Windows 10 GUI - without any success. There is no error.

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder" /reset /T
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder" /inheritance:r /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:(OI)(CI)F

icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder" /save export.txt
type export.txt
```

I expected this output:

```
D:PAI(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)
```

but I get

```
D:PAI(A;OICI;KR;;;AC)(A;CIIO;GR;;;AC)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)
```

Comment: The initial reset should remove non-inherited entries. Maybe something is getting mixed up when you combine `/inheritance:r` and `/grant`. Try the `/grant` first by itself. Then follow up with `/inheritance:r`.

Comment: If it's easier to remember, you can use the "BA" alias instead of the SID string, e.g. `icacls myfolder /grant *BA:(OI)(CI)F`.

Comment: I tried to remove these "unexpected" ACL entries with icacls, the windows UI and in java code - The same result. 
I doubt that this is a matter of the parameter order. Somehow these permissions are automatically restored after each change.

Instead I guess that these acls are defined in some kind of  group policy or anything like this?

Comment: `/reset` the directory and verify that all entries are inherited, i.e. flagged "(I)" in the console output, or "ID" in the saved SDDL. If not, try the command again under a user-mode debugger. For example, with the platform console debugger, run `cdb icacls myfolder /reset`. Then set a breakpoint  via `bp ntdll!NtSetSecurityObject` and start icacls via `g`. When it breaks, verify that icacls sets an SD with a `NULL` DACL via `!sd @r8`. If so, then apparently some rule in the kernel is adding an explicit entry for the application packages group.

Comment: After a reset, all permissions are inherited. The problematic ones  from "C:\Program Files (x86)". 
 
After 
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder" /inheritance:r /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:(OI)(CI)F
no permission is inherited any more. 

I read about permissions being set by group policies are active directories, but this computer is not part of any controlling network.

Comment: I should add that the inherited permissions are:

`ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:(I)(RX)`

`ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)`



while the permissions AFTER replacing all are different:

`ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:(OI)(CI)(Rc,RD,REA,WEA)`
`ZERTIFIZIERUNGSSTELLE FÜR ANWENDUNGSPAKETE\ALLE ANWENDUNGSPAKETE:(CI)(IO)(GR)`

Comment: It seems like these permissions are set by windows to enable the windows defender access folders from its sandbox. Seems like this is new in Windows 1809